# How to select documents in a firestore subcollection that are past a certain date?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, momentjs

I have the following subcollection
`merchants/id/bookings/date`
Here, 'bookings' is the subcollection and 'date' is the name of a document which contains bookings for that date. Here's an example:
`merchants/a9sd7f692934/bookings/25-07-2020`

(1) in my 'where' function, how to define the name of the document?

(2) this involves dates and I am using moment for this. So how to transform a date that comes from firebase inside of the 'where' function?

I would like to get all of the documents that have a date > currentDate and here's what I'm trying but don't know how to proceed

```
//currentDate = 20-07-2020 //typeof String
           firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection('merchants')
          .doc(id)
          .collection('bookings')
          //??? -> how to get doc by its name? how to compare it to a moment date? how to convert it? 
          .where("???", ">", currentDate).get().then(docs => {
              console.log(docs.data())
            }
          })
```

Comment: You use the names of document **fields** in queries, not the names of the documents themselves.   If you don't have a specific field to query, you can't query anything at all.

Comment: The easiest alternative would then be to get all documents from that subcollection and then compare them to the date after they've been retrieved?

Comment: You could certainly try that.  But you're much better off putting a field in each document that contains the date you want to filter.  It needs to be sortable, so a  DD-MM-YYYY string format won't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `FieldPath.documentId`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#documentid

But the way you currently represent dates into the document ID does not lend itself for range operations. Say you want all documents in July, there's no way to filter `25-07-2020` on that.

You'll need to name your documents in most important to least important order, so: `2020-07-25`. Then you can query for:

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('merchants')
  .doc(id)
  .collection('bookings')
  .where(FieldPath.documentId(), ">", "2020-07-")
  .where(FieldPath.documentId(), "<=", "2020-07-31")
  .get().then(docs => {
     docs.forEach((doc) => {
       console.log(doc.data())
     });
  }
```